# Flutter firebase_messaging 6.0.9

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to set up push notifications for the iOS app written in Flutter. I have found the following package: firebase_messaging 6.0.9 (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging).

I am at the 5th point (iOS setup) which is not very clear to me. The part I am struggling with is:

Add the following lines to the `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method in the `AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.swift` of your iOS project.

I have AppDelegate.swift file but I do not know where to put this line of the code. No matter where I put it, the app will crash.

My App Delegate file looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

My background is in JavaScript mostly React, I do not know much about iOS or swift so in an ideal world I would love to read much clearer documentation that would help a newbie like me use this package. I hope there is someone that knows exactly what to do or even used this package before.

Any help is welcome. Is this package any good? Maybe there is a much better package with clearer documentation that you have managed to use successfully? Thank you very much for all the help and comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is **AppDelegate.swift** you just add the condition under in -> Bool {...}.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```